# Speeding up time between date calculation in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, memory-efficient

I have two datetime columns in my pandas dataframe, `df`:

```
d = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1700-01-01', end='2017-01-01', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1':d})
df['date2'] = df['date1'].sample(frac=1).values
```

I am calculating the number of weeks in between these dates using the following:

`df['weeks'] = (df['date1'].subtract(df['date2'])).dt.days/7`

On a dataframe with 11 million rows, this takes longer than I would expect - about 10 minutes.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: You might consider using `numba`... Can you provide a few rows of your data in the question body?

Comment: @COLDSPEED added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy` - convert both columns to `array`s, subtract and last convert to days:

```
df['weeks'] = (df['date1'].values- df['date2'].values) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') / 7
```

Sample:

```
d = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1700-01-01', end='2017-01-01', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1':d})
df['date2'] = df['date1'].sample(frac=1).values
#print (df)

In [292]: %timeit df['weeks'] = (df['date1'].subtract(df['date2'])).dt.days / 7
1 loop, best of 3: 942 ms per loop

In [293]: %timeit df['weeks'] = (df['date1'].values- df['date2'].values) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') / 7
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop
```